# Rails 5 Bootstrap 4 Simple_Form Image Preview before file upload

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

Im building a Rails 5 app, I have a product model and within the new product form I want to be bale to preview the image that will be uploaded.

I have the fields and some JS i got from a tutorial but its not working and I cant seem to get any errors in the console?

Im not the strongest with JS so this could be something small I'm overlooking.

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**My form fields (form Input and Preview)**

```
<%= image_tag("placeholder.png", :id => "img_prev", :class => "preview") %>
<%= f.file_field :image, :class => 'photo_upload', on: {:change => "readURL(this);"} %>
```

**My JS**

```
  // Start Image Preview
  function readURL(input) {
    if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
      var reader = new FileReader();

      reader.onload = function (e) {
        $('#img_prev')
          .attr('src', e.target.result)
          .width(150)
          .height(200);
      };

      reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
    }
  }
```

Comment: anything shows up in the console?

Comment: @Julien no nothing was showing up, I found a solution that works ill post as answer.. Problem was indeed my JS

Comment: @ShawnWilson still no answer?